# How to make three different dummy-columns from 1 column?

Tags: pandas

I am a beginner and I have tried a lot of different solutions, but none of them work.

I have a column, which name is age_group. My column has three different age groups: young, old and middle.

I want to get 3 different dummy-columns from age_group column, named 'young', 'old' and 'middle'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['age_group'])
```